# Using TweetSharp and Rx

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, tweetsharp

I have been trying to create an observable tweeter feed using tweetsharp with the following

```
    public IObservable<IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>> MakeTweetRequest(string screenName)
    {
        var service = new TwitterService();
        var r = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>>(
           (x,y,g) => service.BeginListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline(x), 
              d => service.EndListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline(d) );


        return r(screenName);
    }
```

but i'm just unable to get it to work can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide the signature for `BeginListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few examples using TweetSharp in my [Rx-Demo](https://github.com/ScottWeinstein/Rx-Demo)

Each of these do the same thing, via different Rx methods, which is too `ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineSince` and all future tweets:

- [TwitterFeedAsync](https://github.com/ScottWeinstein/Rx-Demo/blob/master/DisplayUpdates/TwitterFeedAsync.cs)
- [TwitterFeedCreateSync](https://github.com/ScottWeinstein/Rx-Demo/blob/master/DisplayUpdates/TwitterFeedCreateSync.cs)
- [TwitterFeedGenerateSync](https://github.com/ScottWeinstein/Rx-Demo/blob/master/DisplayUpdates/TwitterFeedGenerateSync.cs)

Comment: what is the 'ReplayLastByKey' method?